Is it possible to set the local value of showbreak to "nothing"?
When working with markdown files, I want the Neovim/Vim editor to not show anything when a line is wrapped. The desired behavior can be achieved using these settings in.vimrc:
set wrap
set showbreak=

This makes wrapped lines appearing on the next line without an indicator.
However, I do wish to have something like showbreak=\     for all files, except markdown. I thought this can be done by setting the global showbreak and then adding a special value for it via an autocomd:
file: init.lua
vim.opt.showbreak = '⬉      ' 

file: after/ftplugin/markdown.vim
noremap <buffer> j gj
noremap <buffer> k gk
" setlocal showbreak=..  " this works
setlocal showbreak= " make the global showbreak from vimrc effective
setlocal showbreak=& " make the global showbreak from vimrc effective
setlocal wrap

I am expecting either setlocal showbreak= or setlocal showbreak=& to reset the local value and set it to nothing, but this is not what happens. Instead, the local option takes on the value from the global one.
How can I set showbreak to nothing (undefined, empty) for markdown files, while keeping it as something for all other files?

Maybe could you accept one of the solutions (yours :-)) using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

My take, so far
" after/ftplugin/markdown.vim
noremap <buffer> j gj
noremap <buffer> k gk
noremap <buffer> <up> gk
noremap <buffer> <down> gj
setlocal wrap
setlocal showbreak=NONE " NONE means undefined here

"autocmd BufEnter *.md set showbreak=
"autocmd BufLeave *.md set showbreak=⬉\ \ \ \ \ \ 
" this is not exactly what I want


The solution is mentioned in the docs, it was hiding there all this time.
 :help 'showbreak'

reads
A window-local value overrules a global value.  If the global value is
set and you want no value in the current window use NONE:
    :setlocal showbreak=NONE

Thanks for all the suggestions and help refs

Always :help! :) (cf. How to navigate :help)

It seems that settings a local option to '' reset the option to its default global value
A solution could be:
vim.opt.showbreak = ""
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"FileType"}, {pattern="*", command="setlocal showbreak=>\\ "})
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"FileType"}, {pattern="markdown", command="setlocal showbreak="})

We set the global value to ''.
For all the filetypes we set the showbreak to > .
For the markdown filetype we reset showbreak to '' that makes that it use the global value that ''

I tested it a bit, and vim.opt.showbreak = nil seems to work as well.

The syntax to set an option to its default is to use option&, option&vi, or option&vim. The first uses 'compatible' to decide between the second and third (:help :set-default).
This works with :setlocal even though documented for :set, so :setlocal showbreak& works.
Placing this in your after/ftplugin/markdown.vim should be just fine.

Note, however, that :help global-local applies to showbreak. When such an option is empty, the global option is used. So emptying out showbreak is probably not what you want; you could instead :let &l:showbreak = '  ' to set the local option to 2 spaces.
